# How to not make my app openable?

Tags: android, icons, customization, mobile-development

Sorry if my question is phrased badly, but I'm currently developing an icon pack for android that does not have its own dedicated app, and it shouldn't. I am currently using this: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2399426 as source code (since I'm an android noob) and am having difficulty trying to stop the "open" being an option after the installation of the icon pack, as it simply takes the user to a blank app activity.

Please keep in mind that I am a total noob and have very little experience in java. If it's possible, could someone simply point me in the direction of the file and line I should edit/add to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: why would you like to do so? You are making an app and don't want your app openable?   :/

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest file go to your `MainActivity`'s `<intent-filter>` tag and remove

```
category name="android.app.category.LAUNCHER"
```